# XPAGES AND ONEUI REFERENCE

Tags: xpages, reverse, reverse-proxy, lotus-domino, ibm-oneui

I would like to know if you can import the interface used for XPages (oneui) inside the application without the need to have to referencing the server or extend it.

Thank you

Comment: The documentation for OneUI 2.1 is available here (including CSS resources): http://infolib.lotus.com/resources/oneui/2.1/.  What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Documentation for OneUI 3 is here: http://infolib.lotus.com/resources/oneui/3.0/docPublic/index.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since 8.5.3 OneUI has been delivered via an OSGi plugin on the server. Most modern XPages applications are being built using bootstrap look and feel instead, which is again in the OSGi plugin for XPages Extension Library on OpenNTF. IBM have also moved away from OneUI for IBM Verse and for responsive XPages have adopted bootstrap. I'm not aware of anyone who has tried to pull those into an NSF, and I would not advise it. You may hit Java security exceptions with some of the code, mapping between resources may not work, and there are an immense number of Java classes and other resources. And if you do hit any issues, you are unlikely to find much help to solve them.